# Are there any ways to obtain the style properties of a specific bootstrap class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a website in html and css, and it's my first time using bootstrap in my code. I immediately stumbled across a problem, I found it very difficult to customize a bootstrap class to use it in my own website because I can't find a way to check the style properties of that bootstrap class.Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).?

Comment: @RayeesAC Hello, would this example be okay?
I want to use the bootstrap class "btn", then how can I find out the style included in "btn" to make the edges round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the compiled bootstrap css files to find the style properties for specific classes.
It's usually easier to do this with un-minified files.

In case you don't know where to find this file:

- Go to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases and find the version of Bootstrap you're using
- Under that version, download the bootstrap-[version]-dist.zip file, and unpack it
- Inspect the bootstrap.css file under the css folder and search for the class you want to know more about

Comment: Thank you so much! This will really speedup my work.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

To **[customize bootstrap visit here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/)**.

Add to style to specific class in bootstrap makes to override the style. that is

```css
.btn.btn-primary{
  margin:20px;
  border-radius:60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Are you want like this @YOU JIAN GAN ?

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I wanted to know how to check the styles included in a bootstrap class, I already know how to edit a bootstrap class. :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the bootstrap CSS offline.
I don't know the kind of text editor you are using but using sublime editor, you can get the line of a css property by putting the cursor at the property you want to find in the  html code.
or better still use the find option, mostly ctrl + F

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own css class do this.This code is bad practice.
because we use important css property. Important property in CSS means that all subsequent rules on an element are to be ignored, and the rule denoted by ! important is to be applied. This rule overrides all previous styling rules ​-- the !important property increases its priority.
That means we override Bootstrap css property . With our own css class this will not cause any issue to Bootstrap
but if you use !important to Bootstrap css class it will cause a problem when you are doing a big project.

```css
.mybutton {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  border-radius:100px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mybutton">Primary</button>
```

Or you can use like this too.But if you want to create your own class I prefer above.

```css
.btn.btn-primary{
  margin:20px;
  border-radius:60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: I hope this will help you @YOU JIAN GAN

Comment: Thank you! But I wanted to know how to check the properties of a bootstrap class and not how to customize a bootstrap class. Anyways, I didn't know that you can use ! important to override a bootstrap class, so I learned a new thing. Really appreciate it.